# gunzip on windows with gzip

Tags: openssl, gzip, gunzip

I am trying to use a "gunzip" command on windows as part of a build process that is rigid and cannot change.  Basically in order to compile the FIPS canister for OpenSSL, you have to follow a few commands, and you cannot deviate from them.

This means I have to unzip the source tarball using gunzip as per the documentation (https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.12.pdf, Appendix A).

So far I have found GZip for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm), however I cannot understand how this makes the gunzip command available.  I can see a "gunzip" file, and how that works with the only executable in the installer, but I cannot see how you can run the command "gunzip".

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep compression and decompression logic together, there is one program and command `gunzip` actually runs `gzip` program with option `-d`. On Unix a script using [`!#` syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) does this invisibly.

To do the same on Windows, assuming you put `gzip.exe` in a directory in your PATH, in the same place (or another PATH dir) create a file `gunzip.bat` containing `gzip -d %*`. Or to make the output look nicer, `@echo off` then `gzip -d %*`.

`gunzip -c file | tar x...` should then work as desired (assuming you also have `tar`).